# Terminating thread from inside it's run method in Eclipse-RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, jobs

I have done something like this in my code

```
    public void doWork()
    {
            Job job = new Job("Job")
            {
              @Override
              protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                 while (rsMemName.next()) {
                    Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                        String memId = rsMemName.getString("id");
                        if (doMemberTasks(memId)==false)
                        {
                           cnn.rollback();
                           return;
                        }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                           ex.printStackTrace();                                
                        try {
                           cnn.rollback();
                           return;
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
             }
            }
          }
          job.schedule();
}
```

What i want to do is `exit` from the whole method if `doMemberTasks(memId)` returns false.
But it doesn't `return` from the method and keep looping on `ResultSet`. how can i terminate the thread from the `run` method?
Please give any suggestions how could i achieve that.....
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

This is because return will return only from the thread run method. What you can do is set a variable(flag) probably static, and check its value after the run code to put another return statement.

Comment: thanks for the answer ... i'll take a look at that... isn't there any other alternatives ??

Answer (score 1):

Yeah your best bet would be to have a flag,

```
boolean doWork = true;
...
while( doWork && rsMemName.next(){
...
if (doMemberTasks(memId)==false)
{
    cnn.rollback();
    doWork = false;
    return;
}
```